# Using foreach with array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, explode

Sorry for the newbie question about foreach but I am having trouble using it and would like some help to make it show the result that I want.

Currently I have something like this:

```
 @foreach($object7 as $value7)
      <?php 
            $test4 = $value7->position;
            //$test4 contain Test 1 and Test 2
             $test5 = $value7->startdate;
            //$test5 contain 2017-12-07 and 2018-01-02
              $test6 = $value7->enddate;
           //test6 contain 2018-01-27 and 2018-01-30
            $array4 =  explode(',', $test4);
            $array5 =  explode(',', $test5);
            $array6 =  explode(',', $test6);
       ?>
@foreach($array4 as $item4)
    {{$item4}}
<?php echo " ( " ?>
@foreach($array5 as $item5)
    {{$item5}}
    <?php echo " - " ?>
@endforeach
@foreach($array6 as $item6)
    {{$item6}}
@endforeach 
  <?php echo " )" ?><br>
@endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Which result in this:

Test1 ( 2017-12-07 - 2018-01-02 - 2018-01-27 2018-01-30 )

Test2 ( 2017-12-07 - 2018-01-02 - 2018-01-27 2018-01-30 )

But I want the result to be something like this:

Test 1 (2017-12-07 - 2018-01-02)

Test 2 (2018 -01-27 2018-01-30)

Can somebody help me with this, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of `$object7`?? Also you don't need to use php tags on blade. You can use `@php... @endphp` although you may want to avoid this as much as possible... And all the `.blade.php` accept plain html, so, instead of `<?php echo "(" ; ? >` just write `(`.

Here you can se the documentation about  [Laravel blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)

Comment: Thanks for replying, the $object7 contain an array of values, will update that in the question. And for the replacing of <?php echo "(" ; ?> with just ( will still result the same thing